# In Oracle Apex, interactive report link column, link attributes, why application item substitution string is not working?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

The context:

- Running Oracle Apex 22.2
- Page with a simple interactive report, showing a few columns
- Link column setup, to redirect to a detail form page
- In interactive report region, the "Link Attributes" setting reads: `title="edit record id:#PERSON_ID#" class=&ZXV_CSS_BUTTON.`
- An Application Item named `ZXV_CSS_BUTTON` exists that is set to static value of `cls_my_button`
- Please see the screen shot.

When the page renders the link column does not substitute the `&ZXV_CSS_BUTTON.`, instead the link html output is `...title="edit record id:5" class="&ZXV_CSS_BUTTON."...`

Why is that? The help states application item substitution is valid here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a bug. But this does seem to work when for other columns of type link - this works for me:

Link attributes:

```
title="edit record id:#EMPNO#" class=&P149_CLASS.
```

generates:

```
<a href="f?p=40357:149:17301593089638:::::" title="edit record id:8130" class="myclass">HALL</a>
```

So instead of using the link column in the ir region attributes, just define your own column with a link and the same attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that Koen is right, looks like a bug. Whatever I did and tried `&P22_CLASS.` or `:P22_CLASS` or even `v('P22_CLASS')`, nothing worked. Right-click the icon and *inspect element* - it is always the *string*, never its value.

---

Another workaround, if it is OK for you: instead of putting `class` into "Link Attributes" property, put it into **"Link icon"** instead.

Something like this:

[image]

Does it work? Yes:

[image]